# Code for sorting items in recyclerView

Tags: sorting, android, enum, kotlin

I'm have recyclerView which is needed for displayed for show list of my audio records. I added the ability to sort my audio records. Please take a look at the code that I use for sorting and tell me how it can be improved.

```
enum class AudioRecordSort {

    SortByDate {
        override fun sort(empties: List<AudioRecordEmpty>) {
            Collections.sort(empties, AudioRecordDateComparator())
            if (!isIncrease)
                empties.reversed()
        }
    },
    SortByName {
        override fun sort(empties: List<AudioRecordEmpty>) {
            Collections.sort(empties, AudioRecordNameComparator())
            if (!isIncrease)
                empties.reversed()
        }
    },
    SortBySize {
        override fun sort(empties: List<AudioRecordEmpty>) {
            Collections.sort(empties, AudioRecordSizeComparator())
            if (!isIncrease)
                empties.reversed()
        }
    },
    SortByTime {
        override fun sort(empties: List<AudioRecordEmpty>) {
            Collections.sort(empties, AudioRecordTimeComparator())
            if (!isIncrease)
                empties.reversed()
        }
    };

    val isIncrease: Boolean = true

    abstract fun sort(empties: List<AudioRecordEmpty>)
}
```

I would also like to say that I do not like that in each method I have to call

```
 if (! IsIncrease)
    empties.reversed ().
```

Could this be done in a separate place for everyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that the duplicate code in the sorters looks bad.

To solve this, each sorter should only define the *compare* function, and all the rest should be done by the enum class. Or not even this. It took me a little while of experimenting until the code compiled, but here it is:

```kotlin
enum class AudioRecordSort(
        private val cmp: Comparator<AudioRecordEmpty>
) {
    SortByDate(AudioRecordDateComparator()),
    SortByName(AudioRecordNameComparator()),
    SortBySize(AudioRecordSizeComparator()),
    SortByTime(AudioRecordTimeComparator());

    fun sort(empties: MutableList<AudioRecordEmpty>, asc: Boolean) {
        val cmp = if (asc) cmp else cmp.reversed()
        empties.sortWith(cmp)
    }
}
```

I don't think it can get any simpler than this.

I also fixed the type of the `empties` parameter. You had `List<>`, which in Kotlin is an *immutable* list. I changed that to `MutableList<>`.

I also fixed the `reversed` call to be `reverse`. I bet your IDE has warned you about the "unused result of `reversed`". This in turn means that you didn't test your code thoroughly before posting it here, since otherwise you would have noticed that it doesn't work for `isIncrease == false`.

Next time please post complete, compilable code. The missing parts for this question are:

```kotlin
class AudioRecordEmpty

class AudioRecordDateComparator : Comparator<AudioRecordEmpty> {
    override fun compare(o1: AudioRecordEmpty?, o2: AudioRecordEmpty?) = 0
}

class AudioRecordNameComparator : Comparator<AudioRecordEmpty> {
    override fun compare(o1: AudioRecordEmpty?, o2: AudioRecordEmpty?) = 0
}

class AudioRecordSizeComparator : Comparator<AudioRecordEmpty> {
    override fun compare(o1: AudioRecordEmpty?, o2: AudioRecordEmpty?) = 0
}

class AudioRecordTimeComparator : Comparator<AudioRecordEmpty> {
    override fun compare(o1: AudioRecordEmpty?, o2: AudioRecordEmpty?) = 0
}
```

Comment: How about reversing the `Comparator` instead of the list?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I updated the code. I had planned to do that anyway. Do you know whether this is just a stylistic issue or if there is any measurable benefit? If any, I'd expect it to be quite small.